# Using SOA/EDA in a ECommerce application

Tags: java, e-commerce, soa, eda

As a company directive we are looking at using SOA/EDA as a targeted Architecture for re-factoring our 12 year old ECommerce site.   The site has run its course and has become a challenge in adding new features and keeping it running.

Based on a lot of reading on the topic I see that it is suggested to make use of message topics - that is use document and event type messages - when communicating to the services.

The question I have is this really possible in a ECommerce application?  I can see the use of Web Services and even RMI.  Or does it really depend on if what is being done require sync or async communication channel.

General the application handles request to search data - this is will be done by Solr, ability to manage (edit/add) inventory, move inventory into sales, take bids on items in a sale, process the purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDA is suitable for integrating different systems in a loosely coupled way. May be your inventory management or the bidding. For online search you need fast response times and no loose coupling. For this you can use SOAP, RMI or REST. May be you can use both a async. message broker or ESB and Web Services or a sync. ESB.

To be more specific more details about your requirements and your systems are needed.

Comment: baranco - thanks for the response.  Your comment verifies some additional research I have done in that the answer is "it depends".  So the approach I am going with is that there will be some guidelines put into place to help direct how the communication(s) should be handled.